# Selector to extract element value of type different tagName

Tags: automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, web-testing, testcafe

There is String on my web page which looks as "@Account9 Hey Dude". @Account9 is a link, 'Hey Dude' is span. Please help me to create Selector to extract this  "@Account9 Hey Dude".

note: Can find something like selenium "normalize-space" method.

@Account9

Hey Dude

Comment: my code : <div class=“XYZ123>
     <span class="r-18u37iz">
  <a href="/Account9" dir="ltr" role="link" data-focusable="true" class=“ABC123”>@Account9
  </a>
 </span>
 </div>
   <span class=“ABCxyz123”> :Hey Dude</span>

Comment: So, Selectors can be a single item or a list of items.  So, you could find the class `r-18u37iz`, which is just a single item.  Then it will have 2 child items.  You can then key off of these items when needed to. What are you trying to do with the link and the span?  Are you trying to validate them? concatenate them?....

Comment: What you need is easily achievable with XPath, is it OK for you to extract two elements and then concat their text? With CSS-only case, we will need two selectors, this will allow us to be precise in extracting only the text we need regardless of heavy nested divs.

Answer (score 2):

To create a selector that extracts the inner text of the provided markup:

```html
<div class=“XYZ123> 
    <span class="r-18u37iz"> 
    <a href="/Account9" dir="ltr" role="link" data-focusable="true" class=“ABC123”>@Account9 </a> 
    </span> 
</div> 
<span class=“ABCxyz123”> :Hey Dude</span
```

you need to find the first parent of these elements (`div class=“XYZ123` and `span class=“ABCxyz123”`) , specify CSS selector for it and call `innerText` property.

```js
const targetText = await Selector('<parent_of_these_elements>').innerText;
```